# Can I code in Xcode 5 and then comment out the iOS7 specific code before I submit with Xcode 4?

Tags: ios

There are a few layout issues that I need to resolve for the new iOS version and there is a new method, let’s call it newMethodThatIsNotIniOS6 that I can use code to fix them:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(newMethodThatIsNotIniOS6)]) {
    self.newMethodThatIsNotIniOS6 = PARAMETER;
}
```

This code works fine in Xcode 5 but won’t compile in Xcode 4 because the method is not defined.

Right now, I comment out the code when working on new apps for iOS6, but is there a way to get this to compile in Xcode 4? Alternatively, can I safely code in Xcode 5 and then strip out the iOS7 specific code before I submit with Xcode 4?

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA which restricts you/us from talking about it outside of the official apple developers forum.

Comment: I think that this is a general enough question that he doesn't fall afoul of the NDA.

Comment: @Answerbot That is why I also posted an answer, but when you post a question ask specifically iOS 7 and/or Xcode 5 people might not answer then since that are covered by a NDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude code with a precompile macro's like:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(newMethodThatIsNotIniOS5)]) {
    self.newMethodThatIsNotIniOS5 = PARAMETER;
}
#endif
```

This will only include the method is you are compiling with the iOS 6+ SDK and will not be used if you are compiling with the iOS 5 SDK.

Comment: If the method is only avail in iOS 7 use `__IPHONE_7_0`

Comment: I thought I had tried that and it didn't work—but I must have done something wrong. Thanks.